# Check partially unreadable CoA Product Key

Tags: windows-7, oem, product-key

Two characters are missing on a torn **Windows 7 Professional ACER** sticker.

While I can build a list of matching product keys with combination generator like [this one](http://textmechanic.com/text-tools/combination-permutation-tools/combination-generator/), how could I check its validity?

I found http://janek2012.eu/ultimate-pid-checker/ but I'm not sure it can perform a check against OEM keys.

**UPDATE**

```
// PID Checking ends here

Summary:

       Valid:       0 keys
       Invalid:     576 keys
       Malformed:   0 keys
       Other:       0 keys
 incl. Blacklisted: 0 keys

 Total time:  3 975,826 seconds
```

**UPDATE 2**

Sorry, there was a mistake in my list! One char was wrong.

It finally worked:

```
Product Key : xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx
Profile     : NT 6.1
Validity    : Valid
Product ID  : XXXXX-OEM-9303085-24450
Advanced ID : XXXXX-00186-030-824450-02-1036-7601.0000-0962016
Activation ID   : 
Edition Type    : Professional
Description : Windows 7 Professional OEM:COA
Edition ID  : X15-37341
Key Type    : OEM:COA
EULA        : OEM
Crypto ID   : 186
```

Comment: Do you have an installation with the key?  If you do this is easy to solve, if you don't, contact Acer for assistance.

Comment: "but I'm not sure it can perform a check " - So you didn't even try?

Comment: http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/software-os/f/3524/t/19362388

Comment: Also taking a good picture of the sticker, then use image software to adjust the image to read the product key the eye cannot see.

Comment: @Ramhound I did using Ultimate PID Checker with a complete list of keys. I edited my question with results.

Answer (score 3):

Enter your product key on this page: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows7

If it tells you it's an OEM key, you're good!

FYI... **never** enter your key on a random website. That is a *terrible* idea.

Comment: You are right. While I couldn't use Microsoft page as I had many keys to check, I disconnected network during key checking (PID checker could send key to a remote server).